# Get SQL Server query result and post into a new query after clicking on it

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Right now the webpage is just outputting data as hyperlinks that all take you to the same page.  I want to be able to click on that result and use it in a query on the next page where it will display more details about that query.

```
while ($row = mssql_fetch_row($query_result)) {     
    echo '<td><a href="target.php">'.$row[0].'</a></td></br>';              
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass variables in the href links like:

```
while ($row = mssql_fetch_row($query_result)) {     
    echo '<td><a href="target.php?var1='.$row[0].'" target="blank">'.$row[0].'</a></td></br>';              
    }
```

Now on target that PHP, you may use $_GET or $_REQUEST to get the value of var1 and use it for you query in that page.

```
<?php
//This is the target.php
$var1 = $_GET['var1'];
//Use $var1 for Php MySQL code for the next lines
?>
```

Comment: Yes. By the way if you want to pass more URL variables, you should use & (ampersand) for the next variables. It should be like: href="target.php?var1='.$row[0].'&var2='$row[1]'&var3='$row[2]'"